# User Module modifications

Tags: 7, users

I need to add about 64 custom fields to the user object. These fields will be filled when the user is created and updated from a 3rd-party database when the user logs in.

How would I go about making these modifications? Would I subclass the user or just make a new module to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clive's answer is right for Drupal 6.

For Drupal 7, you'd implement a Field. This field would provide the 64-field form to fill out, the way to display the info, and know how to query the external database. (Obviously there's some room for design improvement here.. I'm chunking all the different pieces into one meta-field, but you could split it out however you want.)

Then you go to `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and add your field to the user account profile. When you add it, there will be an initial configuration page for that field instance, and you'd check 'Display on user registration form.'

Easy as pie, right? :-)

There's a generic field implementation example in the [Examples project](http://drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: +1 that's definitely a more 'Drupal 7' way to do it...you'd probably want to implement some sort of caching though so the field data is only updated when the user is logged in (as per OP's requirement). Otherwise you'll be querying the external database every time the user object is loaded

Comment: The problem is, we don't allow them to register through our Drupal site. They will already have an account through our other registration process and the Drupal site is just an informational page for them.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how to use that field_example.

Comment: The Field API stuff isn't trivial to wrap your head around, but it also has the advantage of making sense once you get it. :-) Another option might be to define an entity for the external table, and then use entityfield module to show the corresponding entity.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing the `$user` object is not really an option as it's a `stdClass` type (this will be changed in Drupal 8 where all entities will derive from the new `Entity` class).

**EDIT**

I've re-read your question and I think this will be a bit more useful:

You can react to user login and creating/updating with the following hooks:

- [`hook_user_login(&$edit, $account)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7)
- [`hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7)
- [`hook_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7)

If you need to load that data back onto the `$user` object for use in Drupal you can do it with [`hook_user_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_load/7):

```
function MYMODULE_user_load($users) {
  // Grab the user ids
  $uids = array_keys($users);

  // Get your data
  $data = function_to_get_data($uids);

  // Loop through the data array (which you should key by uid) and add to the user object
  foreach ($data as $uid => $item) {
    $users[$uid]->extra_item = $item;
  }
}
```

Obviously you can extend that logic as you see fit to add your multiple fields to the `$user` object.

Comment: There will only be one user loaded at a time, why would I need to key by uid?

Comment: You beat me to it :) Drupal 7 has the potential to load multiple users through `hook_user_load()` while Drupal 6 just loads one at a time. When loading the logged in user the array in the `$users` parameter would only contain only one user...but for example in the admin user list it might contain several. It's a good idea for your code to follow that paradigm so you can load multiple users' data at the same time and preserve performance

Comment: But I only need the data for the currently logged in user.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Drupal7.

Comment: Yep I understand, but the correct way to attach data to the `$user` object is to use `hook_user_load()`...and that function expects you to be *able* to load data for as many users as it provides. You can easily test to see if a single user is being loaded though and react accordingly, e.g. `if (count($users) == 1) { $uid = array_shift(array_keys($users)); $users[$uid]->extra_item = the_function($uid); }`

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were going for, I've updated the answer...hope it helps.